# Arm sourcery toolchain linking error

Tags: linker, arm, gnu-toolchain, codesourcery

I want to use standard c function in one of my function

```
void print(const char* format,...) {    
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vsnprintf (buffer,256,format, args);
    va_end (args);
    sendString(buffer);
}
```

Error coming is

```
arm-none-eabi-ld  -o check.elf -T /home/sanju/Arm/check/other/ROM.ld Serial.o irq.o lowlevel.o main.o startup.o \
-L/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib   -lc -lg  -lm
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-svfprintf.o): In function `_svfprintf_r':
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x688): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0xdfc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x10b4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x168c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x16a8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x1a48): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0x1eac): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-dtoa.o): In function `quorem':
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-dtoa.o): In function `_dtoa_r':
dtoa.c:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ui2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x394): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3c4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x3e8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x418): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x5a8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x5ac): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x5b4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x5c0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x5d4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x608): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x61c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x650): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x684): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x688): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x690): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x69c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x6b0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x73c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xa94): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xaa0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xbf8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xc2c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xc58): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xc80): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xc90): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xc9c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xca8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xce8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xcf4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd08): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd10): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd24): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd54): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd78): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xd8c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xdd0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xddc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe00): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe1c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe30): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe44): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xe64): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xef0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xefc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xf08): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xf24): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xf38): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0xf54): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x10c0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x10e8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x1130): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x1144): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x114c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x1160): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x119c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x11a8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x11b0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x11c8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x1200): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x120c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x12cc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x12d8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpge'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x158c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x159c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x15b0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x15bc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x15ec): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
dtoa.c:(.text+0x15f8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-mprec.o): In function `__ratio':
mprec.c:(.text+0xbc0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-mprec.o): In function `_mprec_log10':
mprec.c:(.text+0xbf0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-svfiprintf.o): In function `_svfiprintf_r':
vfprintf.c:(.text+0xf30): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
vfprintf.c:(.text+0xf4c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
make: *** [all] Error 1
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***
```

My makefile is this

```
TOOLCHAIN=arm-none-eabi-

ARM_CPU=arm7tdmi

VPATH= /home/sanju/Arm/check/src /home/sanju/Arm/check/other /home/sanju/Arm/check/include

INCLUDE= /home/sanju/Arm/check/include

CCFLAGS= -mcpu=$(ARM_CPU) -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -Os -Wall

ASFLAGS= -mcpu=$(ARM_CPU) -mthumb-interwork -mfpu=softfpa -Wall


all: Serial.o irq.o lowlevel.o main.o startup.o 

    $(TOOLCHAIN)ld  -o check.elf -T /home/sanju/Arm/check/other/ROM.ld Serial.o irq.o 
lowlevel.o main.o startup.o \

    -L/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib   -lc -lg  -lm

    $(TOOLCHAIN)objcopy -O ihex check.elf check.hex 

    $(TOOLCHAIN)objcopy -O binary check.elf check.bin 



Serial.o : Serial.c Serial.h

    $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc $(CCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -c $< 


irq.o : irq.c irq.h lpc214x.h

    $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc $(CCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -c $< 


lowlevel.o : lowlevel.c lowlevel.h

    $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc $(CCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -c $< 



main.o : main.c lpc214x.h timer0.h Asm.h lowlevel.h type.h Serial.h

    $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc $(CCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -c $< 

startup.o : startup.S 

    $(TOOLCHAIN)as $(ASFLAGS) -o startup.o $< 




.PHONY: clean 

clean : 

    rm -rf *.o  *.elf *.hex *.o *.bin
```

In the target all it fails in linking. I have tried the example with arm-elf toolchain there also i am getting some errors.I have googled a lot for it but did not find any solution for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `gcc` as `ld` frontend.
Change:

```
$(TOOLCHAIN)ld  -o check.elf [...]
```

into

```
$(TOOLCHAIN)gcc  -o check.elf [...]
```

GCC knows to add some necessary options when invoking `ld`.

Comment: i used gcc instead of ld but i am getting some others because gcc try to link it with some crt.o and some symbols are undefined for that file.

Comment: I found this question through Google, and this actually solved my problem. How comes that `gcc` is smarter than `ld`? Shouldn't we stop using `ld` in favor of `gcc` at all then?

Comment: Note that `gcc` is just a frontend for `ld` here. It can tell you the actual `ld` command line used.

Answer (score 3):

Do things go any better when adding "-lgcc" to -L?

Comment: i tried that but i am using linux os so instead of -lgcc -lg is there and i have added that

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `ld` for linking i used `gcc` but it was including the supplied `crt.o` object file so i used `-nostartfiles` and it worked for me.